# Java - Calculation Error

Tags: java, double, numberformatexception

I have wrote the following code to work out the difference between two floating point numbers to two decimal places:

```
double p = (Math.round((Double.parseDouble(a) - Double.parseDouble(a))*100))/100;
```

`a` and `b` are values in a String array that are numbers with decimal places, but obviously in the format of a String. I've tried to convert the String numbers into doubles and carry out the calculation with them but it doesn't seem to be working and throws this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "N/A"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
```

Additional info: This uses data from the web and seemed to work before, but now it seems to have a bug of sorts. How can I solve this, and what's the problem?

Comment: What is the value of a ?

Comment: Either 'a' or 'b' is equal to "N/A". This is a problem.

Comment: Check if these strings use dot as delimiter and not comma

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your `String` variables `a` and `b` are not properly formatted - "N/A" is not a proper `double`.

Please post how you are getting them.

Comment: This has helped me identify the issue, and I'm working on it now. Thank you for pointing that out, don't know how I missed it!

Answer (score 0):

The root of your error is `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "N/A"`

That means `a` or `b` has a value of **N/A**.

Answer (score 0):

There is no b in your code. If you are trying to do something like this:

```
String[] a = {"123","23"} ;
double p = (Math.round((Double.parseDouble(a[0]) - Double.parseDouble(a[1]))*100))/100;
System.out.println(p);
```

then you might have a typo mistake. Because it prints out fine for me.